# RewriteRule with no additional characters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I added the following url rewriteRule to my htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

So as you can see, I want to change the urls like :

```
 http://www.example.com/?url=signup
```

to something like

```
 http://www.example.com/signup
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for me, untill adding a character to my rewriteRule

for example I added a slash at the end of the url:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

It ends by a good but unwanted result :

```
http://www.example.com/signup/
```

so , is there any idea to make urls with variables only and without any additional characters?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Think this is a better fit for the webmasters stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood right, try this:

**UPDATED** to include the basic directives:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I used this one, I typed http://www.example.com/signup and it displayed the home page .. it seems it doesn't recognize the get parameter url

Comment: Please replace [L] with [R,L] so you can **see** the substitution URL. to understand what's going on. Is that the real testing URL or are you in a local host or a different domain? If it doesn't work, please copy-paste into your question the complete .htaccess content.

Comment: I used it , it shows in the address bar : http://www.example.com/D:/example/?url=signup
where example is my project name, and D: is the hard drive, also , the .htaccess file doesn't contain more than the two lines I posted, for now

Comment: and it says that I don't have permission to access  D:/example/index.php on this server

Comment: Updated my answer. Copy-paste it into your .htaccess file and give another it try. From you comment the rule is working, anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, it works!! :D ... +1 , I'm trying to understand the problem

Comment: You are welcome. Basically the problem is mod_rewrite requires this `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews` to work.